# No resource found that matches the given name @integer/google_play_services_version

Tags: android, google-play-services

I inherited a project, and we would ideally like to remove the import below from our gradle file:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:${playServicesVersion}"
```

However, once we remove this, we get the error:

```
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').
```

I have searched everywhere within the project, and I cannot find anything that is tying us to any gms classes or Google Play Store items.  I am having trouble understanding why it's forcing the version implementation when I don't see anything needing it.  Are there any suggestions on places to look for this kind of thing to remove this dependency?

Comment: Do you have `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end of the app `build.gradle` and `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'` in buildscript.dependencies of project `build.gradle`

Comment: We do not have either of those in our build.gradle file.  It does not seem as if we have any google-services related lines of code across our entire config/app.  We are wanting to remove any dependency on Google Play Services.  It does not seem that the app uses it, so we would like to remove this to reduce the weight of the app.  The line we removed is the "compile" line listed above, when the error started showing.

Comment: Find in the entire app the string `google_play_services_version`, it still appears somewhere, mostly in `AndroidManifesh`, then remove that line, if no, a Rebuild may help

Comment: That string does not exist in the project anymore (it has been completely removed - there are absolutely no references to any play services lines of code anymore).  I have cleaned, re-built, invalidated caches, etc.  The error keeps showing, for some reason. :(

Comment: I think some other library is using gms and still looking for the version code, Try removing some of them to see if it helps. Otherwise, a dummy solution I can give you is creating another project to refresh everything and move the code to it.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought about another library using it.  I'll check and get back to you.  Thank you!

Comment: What do you get when you try a ./gradlew app:dependencies ? Like @TamHuynh says, something else may be pulling in Play services libraries.

Comment: Looks like when I remove the compile line above, as well as the reference in our Manifest to the 'google_play_services_version', it still errors with the "No resource found" error, but when I run gradlew dependencies command above, no reference to the play services are found.  I should have noted also that the error is coming from this Manifest located in the build path: "App/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml".  I checked, and there are no other references to play services in the project.

Comment: I created a new project and did all the same imports for libs, minus PayPal SDK and Stripe, and the project compiled fine, so it may be attributed to either PayPal or Stripe, although I can't seem to narrow it down further.. very strange